# how can i override method save plugin joomla 4

Tags: php, joomla-4.x, plugin

I have custom plugin and I want to do something when my plugin save in admin panel of Joomla 4 . How can I override save method in plugin ?

Comment: I think you would get an onContentBeforeSave event being triggered when you tried to save the changes in the admin plugin form. If you wrote another plugin which listened for that, would that meet your needs?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Content plugin and use the `onContentBeforeSave` method like Robbie Jackson suggested.

If for some unknown reason it does not work, you could always write a system plugin and use `onAfterInitialise` or `onAfterRoute` and do something there. Only use this when you cannot use anything else.

Do you use an IDE like PHPStorm or VisualStudio? If you combine it with XDebug, you could set break points, and step through Joomla's code to find the places that you could trigger to do something with your code.